# TreeMap ClassCastException

Tags: java, generics, gson, classcastexception, treemap

Cannot figure out where the String casting is coming from that is causing this ClassCastException. I've cleared out the map so that it only holds a single entry (115,1563) and I ensured both parameters were integers.

First I read from a file and populate the scoreMap.

```
private void populateScoreMap(String toConvert)
{
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    ScoreRecord.scoreMap = (TreeMap<Integer,Integer>) gson.fromJson(toConvert, ScoreRecord.scoreMap.getClass());

}
```

ScoreRecord class

```
public class ScoreRecord
{
    public static SortedMap<Integer,Integer> scoreMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
}
```

Then I try to add an entry in the ScoreGraph class

```
private void addTodaysScore() {
    Integer todaysScore = getIntent().getIntExtra("score",0);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Integer dayOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    ScoreRecord.scoreMap.put(dayOfYear,todaysScore);
    }
```

Exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Integer.java:1044)
at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:593)
at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.ScoreGraph.addTodaysScore(ScoreGraph.java:63)
```

Comment: Can you dump all the keys in the scoreMap? It's failing inside `compareTo` which would be the case if there was already a String key in the map.

Comment: oh is that possible? even though the scoreMap is type defined to use integer keys and values?... didn't think that would be possible, i'll take a look through the data that's in the map.

Comment: Can you share your complete code of this class?

Comment: It's definitely possible – remember that generics are just used for type-checking by the compiler while the underlying type is simply `Object`. The checks can easily be overridden with casts, look out for code like this: `((SortedMap)scoreMap).put("hello", "world");` https://ideone.com/CF9lAB

Comment: getIntent().getIntExtra("score",0) share these methods as well.

Comment: I made edits to add some more relavent code. Do you think the gson conversion is causing the issue? Is it reading from the file and putting the entries into the map as strings??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the result of `ScoreRecord.scoreMap.getClass()` is a Java class which does not contain the information relating to generics. In your specific case, it is just `SortedMap` which is equivalent to `SortedMap<Object, Object>` rather than `SortedMap<Integer, Integer>`.

What you need to do is to create what Gson calls a »type token«. This will give Gson the required hints to be able to parse your collection successfully:

```
private void populateScoreMap(String toConvert)
{
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    Type collectionType = new TypeToken<SortedMap<Integer, Integer>>(){}.getType();

    ScoreRecord.scoreMap = gson.fromJson(toConvert, collectionType);
}
```

This is also explained in Gson's [documentation](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#collections-examples)